# Rule for permutation of the trace of a Kronecker product, e.q. $ Tr(A\otimes B \otimes C \otimes D) = Tr(A\otimes C \otimes B \otimes D)$?

Tags: linear-algebra

Given two column vectors $A,B$ and two row vectors $C,D$, is there some rule to rewrite the trace of their Kronecker product:

$$ Tr(A\otimes B \otimes C \otimes D) = ? $$

*Specifically, I'm looking for some way to relate this expression to another expression like*

$$ Tr(A\otimes B \otimes C \otimes D) = Tr(A\otimes C \otimes B \otimes D) + \ldots $$

Comment: The Kronecker product is a vector. What do you mean by its trace?

Comment: @user1551 Why should the product be a vector? The Kronecker product of two vectors yields a matrix. Then the Kronecker product of two matrices yields another matrix

Comment: The Kronecker product of an $m\times n$ matrix and a $p\times q$ matrix has size $mp\times nq$. If $A,B,C,D$ are (column) vectors, the result must be a vector.

Comment: For square matrices it's quite easy to show that ${\rm Tr} \, A \otimes B = {\rm Tr}\, A \cdot {\rm Tr} \, B$. In that case the order isn't important.

Comment: @user1551 Ah okay, $C$ and $D$ are row vectors, I'll edit the question

Comment: @user1551 What do you mean by $A\otimes B=AB$, i.e. which product do you mean on the right-hand side? (And yes, all vectors have the same length)

Comment: @JakobH Oh, sorry, I thought you mean $B,D$ are row vectors.